# Получить url картинки с диска

Tags: url, javascript, изображения

Доброго времени суток! Можно ли получить `url` картинки с диска? То-есть открыть окно выбора файла и получить url выбранной картинки, не загружая её?

Comment: Никак. Вы можете получить только название файла.

Comment: для чего вам это? если для вывода картинки в img тогда надо пользоваться js и Data:url

Answer (score 1):

Ссылку к файлу получить нельзя, невозможно. Можно получить размер, имя, формат, но не ссылку.